# Problema ao fazer deploy no heroku com apigility

Tags: php, heroku

Estou tentando subir uma api criada com Apigility para o heroku. A aplicação compila corretamente, porém ao fazer qualquer request, eu recebo um erro 500 como retorno. No log do heroku, eu vejo o seguinte erro:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend\Console\Console' not
>   found in
>   /app/vendor/zfcampus/zf-content-negotiation/src/Factory/RequestFactory.php:22

Não encontrei muitos tutoriais por ai, e aqueles que encontrei não disponibilizavam muitos detalhes do passo a passo para subir a aplicação.

Alguém já passou pelo mesmo problema? Qual a solução para esse erro?